# Retrieve value by jQuery from href parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to display dialog form with jquery. However, I want to be able to pass a value into this form from href parameter that opens this form.

My jquery:

```
// Set SerialNumber dialog form
$("#setsn-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 350,
    modal: true
});

$(".set-serialnumber")
.button()
.click(function () {
$("#setsn-form").a
    $("#sethor-form").dialog("open");
});
```

And href link is this:

```
<a href='#?SerialNumber=123456789' title='Set Serial Number' class='set-serialnumber'>
```

How can get `SerialNumber=123456789` in that dialog form?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".set-serialnumber").button().click(function () {
    var serial = this.href.split('?').pop();

    // somehow pass to dialog ?
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input id="serialnumber" type="hidden" value="SerialNumber=123456789">
<button id="open-dialog">Open Dialog</button>
<div id="serial-modal">
    <p id="dialog-serial"></p>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$("#serial-modal").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  width: 350,
  modal: true
});

$("#open-dialog").click(function () {
  $("#serial-modal").dialog("open");
  $("#dialog-serial").html($("#serialnumber").val());
});
```

Working JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/SRELC/1/